# Searching for some optimizations on a simple c calculation

Tags: c, optimization

I am currently searching for an optimization on a simple c calculation, I have 2 solutions for now, but I don't know which one will have the best performance :

**Code 1 :**

```
u32_tmp = 0x01FFBBAA; //Random value...
tab[0] = (u32_tmp & 0xFC00000) >> 18; 
tab[1] = (u32_tmp & 0x3F000) >> 12 ; 
tab[2] = (u32_tmp & 0xFC0) >> 6 ; 
tab[3] =  u32_tmp & 0x3F;
```

**Code 2 :**

```
u32_tmp = 0x01FFBBAA; //Random value...
tab[3] = u32_tmp & 0x3F;
u32_tmp>>=6;
tab[2] = u32_tmp & 0x3F;
u32_tmp>>=6;
tab[1] = u32_tmp & 0x3F; 
u32_tmp>>=6;
tab[0] = u32_tmp & 0x3F;
```

Which one is "the best" in your point of view ?

Comment: When you tested them, which was faster?  That is the one I would choose.

Comment: Do the first in a loop a a several thousand times, while timing it. Then do that many times. Then calculate the average time. Then do the same for the second alternative. Then compare the average times.

Comment: I will try both solution that's for sure. My question is more a theoritical question

Comment: But that question can't be answered on a purely theoretical basis, because it depends on what the compiler does with it.

Comment: Or check the assembler code and compare. If one have many fewer instructions then it likely that it's faster. Also be careful about compiler optimization levels, as high optimization may generate faster code for one alternative, but unoptimized the other alternative may be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Code 1` shows which bits you extract from the values much more clearly than `Code 2`, in my opinion. That's the one I'd chose.

If performance is critical, there's a good chance an optimizing compiler will transform both these snippets into similar assembly code - but if this is a greater concern than code readability, you can look at the assembly code generated in both cases and/or do performance testing on the two variants.

Comment: +1 I agree - readability is much more important than trying to do small optimizations like that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe on a reasonable compiler optimizing such code is not at all worth it. Most of the time no matter how hard you try to optimize the code with some hacks it may even turn out to perform worse. Nowadays compilers do a **really** good job in optimizing code. Optimizing the logic is what can make the difference. I will be surprised if benchmarking the above two versions even shows a consistent advantage of one of the versions with optimizations turned on.

Comment: Agreed, this code is translated to almost the same set of instructions in any CPU. Any smart compiler will make the difference unnoticeable.